Finding $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\frac{\text{ones in binary representation of }n^t}{\text{total digits of binary representation of }n^t}$
I have been learning MATLAB and as a fun challenge to myself, I looked into this question, something I came up with a few months ago. I got surprised by the results and don't really understand what is happening.

Let $f=f_t(n)=\frac{\text{ones in binary representation of }n^t}{\text{total digits of binary representation of }n^t}$, $f_\infty=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}f_t$
Below is a screenshot of some of my results. There are 25 lines representing $n=1$ through $n=25$. The numbers on the horizontal axis represent $\frac{t}{100}$ and $f$ is on the vertical axis.

As you can see, the limit of $f$ as $t\to\infty$ seems to converge for every line. I conjecture that it does for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I am more interested in what they converge to. Here is a chart of what different values of $n$ seem to approximately converge to for $1\le n\le25$:
$$
\begin{array} {|l|l|}\hline n & f_{\infty} \\ \hline 1                       & 1 \\ \hline 2,4,8,16 & 0 \\ \hline 3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25 & 0.5 \\ \hline 6,20 & 0.3 \\ \hline 10,22 & 0.4 \\ \hline 12,24 & 0.2 \\ \hline 14,18 & 0.375 \\ \hline  \end{array}
$$
I suspect that the values for $n = 6,10,12,14,18,20,22,24$ might be incorrect because they are spread not that close to their approximations. From the graph, it looks a lot more like they mostly converge to different values. I notice these values of $n$ are even and not divisible by $2$.

Taking a stab at solving this:
$$\begin{align*}
&\text{For }n\in\{a^k\space|\space k\in\mathbb{N}\}:f_\infty(n)=f_\infty(a)\tag{1} \\ 
&\text{For }n=1:\text{Obviously $f_\infty(1)=1$ because $f_t(1)$ is constant.}\tag{2} \\
&\text{For }n=2:f_\infty(2)=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}=0\tag{3} \\
&\text{For }n=2^k:f_\infty(2^k)=0\text{ because of (1) and (3).}\tag{4}
\end{align*}$$
That's as far as I can get with that approach

Simplifying $f$:
$$f=\frac{\text{ones in binary representation of }n^t}{\text{total digits of binary representation of }n^t}=\frac{\newcommand{\wt}{\text{wt}}\wt(n^t)}{\lfloor t\log_2 n\rfloor+1}$$
where $\wt(x)$ represents the binary weight of $x$ and $\lceil x\rceil$ represents the ceiling function of $x$.

Edit: I found this paper and think it might help me simplify the sum. I haven't figured it out yet though.

Interesting question! I think you are right, the paper you linked is key to understanding what is happening. You can express the fraction of ones in the binary representation of an integer $a$ by $\frac{A(a+1,2)-A(a,2)}{\log_2(a)}$. It’s easy to show that $\frac{(A(a+1,2)-E(a+1,2))-(A(a,2)-E(a,2)}{log_2(a)}\to 1/2$ as $a\to \infty$, so the challenge is to figure out how the differences of $E$ functions behave when $a$ is a large power of $n$. I won’t have time to try working this out, but I hope this partial solution is helpful!

Surely the total digits of $n^t$ is not $\lceil n^t\rceil$, but $\lfloor t\log_2n\rfloor+1$.

One more quick back of the envelope calculation. Your numerics seem to suggest that the proportion of 1s in the binary powers of odd numbers converge to 1/2. Let's suppose this is true. Then you can calculate the limiting proportion of 1s for any other even integer. For example, $3^k$ has roughly $k\log_2(3)$ binary digits of which (if the conjecture is right) roughly $k/2\log_2(3)$ are equal to 1. Then the binary representation of $6^k$ is the same as $3^k$ but with an extra $k$ zeros making the new limiting proportion equal to $\frac{1/2\log_2(3)}{\log_2(3)+1}\approx 0.307$.

So you only need to show that the proportion of 1s converges to 1/2 for odd numbers, which means you only need to show that $\frac{\Delta E(n^k,2)}{k\log_2(n)} \to 0$ when $n$ is odd and unequal to 1.

@J.G. Good catch!

Unfortunately you can't in general replace it with $\lceil t\log_2n\rceil$. That's wrong if $n$ is a power of $2$.

@forgottenarrow I completely forgot to put the part about how I thought odd numbers converged to $0.5$ into my question. Thanks for the help

It is widely conjectured but (I think) not proved that, in the limit, half the bits of $3^n$ are ones. See https://oeis.org/A011754 for some discussion and links and references to the literature. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4390898/powers-of-3-in-binary-how-can-you-prove-this-evidency

See also Stolarsky, Kenneth B. “The Binary Digits of a Power.” Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 71, no. 1 (1978): 1–5. https://doi.org/10.2307/2042203.

FYI, the number of 1's in a binary numeral is often called its "Hamming weight".

As @GerryMyerson mentioned in the comments, it appears that the limit:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} f_t(n) = 1/2 \text{ for } n = 3$$
is currently a conjecture. As suggested by your simulations, I will assume that the limit holds for all odd $n$ greater than 1.
If this is the case, then we can directly compute $f_{\infty}(n)$ for all even $n$. You already computed $f_{\infty}(n)$ when $n$ is a power of $2$. Let's suppose instead that $n = p2^k$ where $p$ is an odd, positive integer (not equal to $1$) and $k \geq 1$.
For each $t$, notice that $p^t$ has exactly $\lceil t\log_2(p)\rceil$ binary digits. Define the functions $h,g:\mathbb{N}_0 \to \mathbb{Z}$ by
$$h(n) = \#\text{ of ones in the binary representation of }n.$$
and
$$g(t) = h(p^t) - \frac{\lceil t\log_2(p)\rceil}{2}.$$
Then the conjecture states,
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}f_t(p) = \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{h(p^t)}{\lceil t\log_2(p)\rceil} = \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{2} + \frac{g(t)}{\lceil t\log_2(p)\rceil} = \frac{1}{2}.$$
We may therefore conclude that $g(t) = o(t)$. This tells us that for any constant $c > 0$,
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{h(p^t)}{ct} = \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\lceil t\log_2(p)\rceil}{2}}{ct} = \frac{\log_2(p)}{2c},$$
where we use the fact that $\frac{\lceil tx\rceil}{t} \to x$ for any $x$.
Now, to compute $f_{\infty}(n)$, we note that for any $t$, $n^t = p^t2^{kt}$ has the same binary representation as $p^t$ except with $kt$ zeros added to the end. Therefore, $h(n^t) = h(p^t)$, but $n$ now has $\lceil t\log_2(p)\rceil + kt$ binary digits. It follows that:
$$f_{\infty}(n) = \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{h(n^t)}{\lceil t\log_2(p)\rceil + kt} = \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{h(p^t)}{t\left(\log_2(p) + k\right)} = \frac{\log_2(p)}{2(\log_2(p) + k)},$$
where the second equality once more uses the fact that $\frac{\lceil tx\rceil}{t} \to x$.
We can use this formula to update the table you posted in the statement of your problem:
$$\begin{array}{|l|l|}\hline
n & f_{\infty}\\ \hline
6 & 0.3066\\ \hline
10 & 0.3495\\ \hline
12 & 0.2211\\ \hline
14 & 0.3687\\ \hline
18 & 0.3801\\ \hline
20 & 0.2686\\ \hline
22 & 0.3879\\ \hline
24 & 0.1728\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Edit: It's worth noting that the formula works for all integers $n$ greater than $1$. When $n$ is odd, $k = 0$ and we get $1/2$ as conjectured. When $n = 2^k$, the formula reduces to $\frac{0}{k} = 0$ as expected. When $n = 1$, the formula reduces to an indeterminate $\frac{0}{0}$ form.
